# error al elegir paciente para imprimir factura en c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, stored-procedure

tengo un inconveniente al tratar de elegir un paciente en una consulta para que me pueda imprimir su factura, cuando elijo el paciente que es y le doy a imprimir me hala el paciente que esta registrado primero, es decir la primera consulta, y así me pasa con todos los demás.

aqui parte del sprocedure que tengo

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[Sp_SelectFacturas]
  as
select ID,IdCliente,NombreCliente,EdadCliente,SexoCliente,
NombreDoctor,EspecialidadDoctor,Procesos,Costo,Descuento,Pago,Total,Estatus,Fecha from Facturas
```

y la imagen de como es que sale 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el código del boton factura

```
  DetalleFactura df = new DetalleFactura();
                df.lblnombre.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["NombreCliente"].Value.ToString();
                df.lblsexo.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["SexoCliente"].Value.ToString();
                df.lbledad.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["EdadCliente"].Value.ToString();
                df.lbldoctor.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["NombreDoctor"].Value.ToString();
                df.lblstatus.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Estatus"].Value.ToString();
                df.lblfecha.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Fecha"].Value.ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                df.lblProcedimientos.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Procesos"].Value.ToString();
                df.lblcosto.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Costo"].Value.ToString();
                df.lblsubtotal.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Costo"].Value.ToString();
                df.lblprocesofactura.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Costo"].Value.ToString();
                df.lblDescuento.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Descuento"].Value.ToString();
                df.lblpagosfactura.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Pago"].Value.ToString();
                df.lbldescuentofactura.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Descuento"].Value.ToString();
                df.lblPago.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Pago"].Value.ToString();
                df.lblDescuento.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Descuento"].Value.ToString();
                df.lbltotalfactura.Text = dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Total"].Value.ToString();

                if (dgvFactura.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Factura"].Selected)
                {

                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["IdCliente"].Value.ToString());
                    using (GRUDENTEntities db = new GRUDENTEntities())
                    {

                        var oImage = db.Facturas.Find(id);
                        df.Show();

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás recuperando la factura a traves del método `Find`, según la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/querying/index?redirectedfrom=MSDN) te recupera la entidad a través de la propiedad definida como Primary Key.

> El método Find de DbSet usa el valor de clave principal para intentar
>   buscar una entidad cuyo seguimiento realiza el contexto.

Si te fijas, a tu variable `id`, que es la que usas en el `Find`, le estas pasando el valor de la celda `IdCliente`.

Asegurate de que esa columna sea la PK y no la otra que tienes definida como `ID`, según se ve en tu procedure.